# How to link static library into static library in Eclipse CDT

Tags: c++, linux, linker, static-libraries, eclipse-cdt

I have 3 projects A, B and C.
A is universal and used by B and eventually C.
B is a bit more special and up to now only used by C.

Now as I want A and B to be reused as much as possible I thought of both being static libraries.

So I link A and B to static libraries and C to an executable, but when I want to link C
it gives me some `undefined reference` errors on A functions. So I added the library A to the linker options to resolve this but it did not help.

So I thought: when I want to deploy B then I also will have to deploy A to be able to link. Is there a way to link the static library A into static library B so I do not have to deploy 2 files?

And if so, how do I achieve this with Eclipse CDT, because I cant find a place where to define additional targets for the archiver.

**Addition**

I am working under linux but the things should also work under windows. But mainly I need a solution for linux to keep going with the development.

**EDIT**

Right now I "solved" the problem by linking A and B into static libraries and then use the remaining *.o files to link them into the executable but I do not consider this as good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a static library cannot be linked with another static library. I think because a static library is not an executable code and so full linking process (mainly references resolution) is not done. It's done only for dynamic libraries and executables.

Comment: So you say I should compile them into dynamic libraries?

Comment: yes, to deploy B alone, w/o C, it's better to make it as a dynamic library

Comment: Oh sorry forgot to mention I am under linux but I am trying to be platform independent. Of course linking cannot be done platform independent, so I need at first a working linux version.

Comment: Still I'd like to have everything linked in one file so I just hand out an executable and that is it.

Comment: I guess so because it is only a demo application, that should be handled as easy as possible.

Answer (score 3):

change your link order.
C use B, and B use A. C does not use A directly, right?

you write:

```
gcc -o C -lA -lB
```

it will not work. you write

```
gcc -o C -lB -lA
```

it works.

if CDT, you could go to **option->C/C++ Build->setting->XXX C linker->Libraries**, and change A and B's order.

Another way: use -u option.

see this:
http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html
BUT, I NEVER succeeded.
May anyone tell me how to use -u option?